# custom message in php mysql error/warning

Tags: php, mysql

I have several months as tables in mysql. When i use the below code for a table name that doesn't exist in my database i want to display a custom message as "Invalid Month".But in addition to this message i am getting a warning as

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\student_portal\admin\update_attd.php on line 102
```

i Generate the table name dynamically based on the user input

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM `tablename`";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql); 
        if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){ //this is the line that shows the warning
            echo " invalid month";
        }
```

how can i avoid that warning message?

Comment: you can check connectivity $con is correct or not?

Comment: How do you check if $conn is ok or not?

Comment: @AndréGadonski I do that separately in connect.php and i used {include "connect.php"}

Comment: @Giri Dharan wow, alive again! So, today it´s works?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your call to `mysqli_prepare()` is failing. The function returns false when it fails.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @verv how can i echo a custom msg alone??

Comment: @Giri Dharan, what do you mean? I don't understand the question.

Comment: if that particular msqli_prepare statement is failed then i want to echo a statement defined by me.i dont want that warning to display